# error running shared postrotate script for mysql

Tags: mysql, cron

I installed a new Ubuntu 18.04 server with mysql, and I receive the following error by email daily:

```
Cron <root@www> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/*log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem according to https://serverfault.com/questions/325171/debian-mysql-error-running-shared-postrotate-script-for-var-log-mysql-log:

My password for user `debian-sys-maint` was not correct. I updated the password with:

```
update user set authentication_string=password("<password>") where user="debian-sys-maint";
```

Comment: Not 'I think', you did!

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, in my case this error resulted from the postrotate script being run before the startup of mysql was finished. By just delaying logrotate.timer or the cron job by e.g. 60 secs, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the password for debian-sys-maint did not fix the problem.
I found the solution after reading "man mysqladmin".
There the descripion of the option --defaults-file says:

`Exception: Even with --defaults-file client programs read .mylogin.cnf.`

The command `mysql_config_editor print` showed

```
[client]
user = root
host = localhost
```

As this overrules what is in --defaults-file the authentication failure occurred. The file /root/.mylogin.cnf was probably created when I was trying to get familiar with mysql_config_editor a few months ago.

Removing /root/.mylogon.cnf solver the problem for me.